# Int division in scala

Tags: scala

I have two `Int` values in Scala.

```
scala> val a = 3
a: Int = 3

scala> val b = 5
b: Int = 5
```

Now, I want to divide them and get Float. With as little boilerplate as possible.

If I do `a/b`, I get

```
scala> a/b
res0: Int = 0
```

I cannot do simple Java `(float)`.

```
scala> ((Float)a)/b
<console>:9: error: value a is not a member of object Float
              ((Float)a)/b
                      ^
```

What should I do?

Comment: maybe you could re-title this to [float division in scala?]

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123572/scala-divide-two-integers-and-get-a-float-result

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following line followed by its result should solve your problem.

```
scala> a.toFloat/b
res3: Float = 0.6
```

Answer (score 18):

Alternative answer that uses type ascription:

```
scala> (a:Float)/b
res0: Float = 0.6
```