# Why does 3/2 equal 1 instead of 1.5?

Tags: scala, double

Why Scala doesn't do the math properly like all other languages? With float the same thing.

```
var x: Double = 3/2
```

returns `1` but 3/2 should equal 1.5.

Comment: Which other languages are this?

Comment: VBA returns 1.5 for example.

Comment: VBA is not all other languages...

Comment: Actually most C-derived languages will return 1. So Scala does it for Java compatibility, Java for C++ compatibility, and C++ for C compatibility, and maybe some more steps back...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, you are right. But in Scala it is also about strong typing. Simple numeric operations should return the same type as themselves, so dividing an `Int` by an `Int` must produce an `Int`. The OP is thinking of languages with loose or run-time typing.

Comment: @Tim No, static typing does not at all imply "Simple numeric operations should return the same type as themselves". And they don't in Scala (or Java, or C++, or C): arithmetic operations on `Short` and `Byte` return `Int`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Fair point. And of course Scala has implicit conversions that can confuse things as well.

Comment: Quote from Odersky: "Scala/Java's conventions wrt
division are broken.
I would much rather have
  `1/2 = 0.5`
  `1 div 2  = 0`
Nevertheless I don't think we'll change anything... One of the principles of Scala's design was to identify what we
really care about, and not to shy away from being different there. The
flipside is that we also identify
areas where we don't care too much. In these areas we simply adopt the
standard Java conventions." http://www.scala-archive.org/scala-Number-explicit-conversion-tp1993817p1993825.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the difference between [integer literal](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#integer-literals) and [floating point literal](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#floating-point-literals)

```
2    // integer literal representing a value of type Int
2.0  // double precision floating point literal representing a value of type Double
```

Hence the expression `3/2` is typed as `Int` because `2` is an `Int` and `1` is an `Int`, therefore we have division between integers. Because `Int` represent whole numbers we have

```
assert(3 / 2 == 1)
```

The key is to understand that *literals* are just a special shorthand notation representing a particular value in a particular type. For example consider character literals

```
assert('3' / '2' == 1)   // because 51 / 50 == 1
```

Confusion might stem from the fact they look quite similar

```
val x: Int    = 2
val x: Double = 2.0
val x: Char   = '2'
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to write the function which takes two integers and returns Double which represents the number of division of one integer to another I should do it like this?   def divide(x:Int, y:Int) = x.toDouble/y.toDouble

Comment: If one of your operands is a `Double` the result will be a `Double`. So either write a `Double` literal (`a / 2.0`) or when you have two `Int` variables convert one (`a / b.toDouble`).

Comment: @IvanSavchenco Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123572/scala-divide-two-integers-and-get-a-float-result